# insert multi dates alarm in c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

im trying to do multi dates alarm but i don't know the code that can make it possible

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
           


            if (currentTime.Hour==alarmTime.Hour && currentTime.Minute==alarmTime.Minute && currentTime.Second == alarmTime.Second)

            {
                timer1.Stop();
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

in  `DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker1.Value`;
i want to put more than 1 value which is `dateTimePicker1` and `dateTimePicker2` and `dateTimePicker3` and `dateTimePicker4` and `dateTimePicker5`
is there any way to make this ?

i have tried this

```
 DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker2.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker3.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker4.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime = dateTimePicker5.Value;
```

but it doesnt work

"function named 'alarmTime' is already defined in this scope"

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read the tutorial

Comment: How do you usually store multiple things of the same type together? You use an array or collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define the same object with the same name, in this case `alarmTime`

Do something like:

```
 DateTime alarmTime1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime2 = dateTimePicker2.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime3 = dateTimePicker3.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime4 = dateTimePicker4.Value;
 DateTime alarmTime5 = dateTimePicker5.Value;
```

Or as jmcilhinney suggest, use an `array` or a `List`

```
List<DateTime> alarmTime = new List<DateTime>();
alarmTime.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value);
alarmTime.Add(dateTimePicker2.Value);
alarmTime.Add(dateTimePicker3.Value);
alarmTime.Add(dateTimePicker4.Value);
alarmTime.Add(dateTimePicker5.Value);
```

Suppose you have a list of several alarms called `alarms` (in plural)

```
List<DateTime> alarms = new List<DateTime>();   
alarms.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value);
alarms.Add(dateTimePicker2.Value);
alarms.Add(dateTimePicker3.Value);
alarms.Add(dateTimePicker4.Value);
alarms.Add(dateTimePicker5.Value);
```

Then you can go one by one doing the following (for each alarm in your list, check this...):

```
foreach(var alarm in alarms) {

    if (currentTime.Hour==alarm.Hour && currentTime.Minute==alarm.Minute && currentTime.Second == alarm.Second)
    {
       //your stuff
```

Comment: There may be reasons to use discrete variables. Generally though, I'd think that an array would be the best option if you know the number of values won't vary. Unlike discrete variables, you can loop over an array. A collection would be preferable if the number of values may vary. Also, the variable name for an array or collection should be plural rather than singular.

Comment: i tried it but i got this error : Collection initialization can be simplified

Comment: @zazomama that seems to be a warning, maybe try var alarmTime = or _ alarmTime but is only a warning.

Comment: @zazomama, that's not an error. That's just a suggestion for simplifying the code. If you pay attention, VS will actually implement the suggestion for you. Also, the code as written could be simplified but, in a real situation, you'd probably create the collection and add the items separately, so that simplification is not possible.

Comment: @jmcilhinney for sure! I didnt wont be complex because I think he/shes learning

Comment: 'List<DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Hour'
'List<DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Second'
'List<DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Minute'

Comment: @zazomama take in consideration you have to add an item of the same kind of the list. If List<datetime> you have to add a datetime with the method Add

Comment: how can i do that can you write the code please sir ?

Comment: @zazomama no problem, thanks to you and good coding!